# How can I write/save a 2 dimensional string to a textfile? C# windows form

Tags: c#, text-files, multidimensional-array, windows-forms-designer

when I use File.WriteAllLines it only accepts 1D arrays. right now, I just have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < BookList_Array.Length; x++)
{
    writer.WriteLine(BookList_Array);
}
```

with BookList_Array being the 2D dimensional array. when i enter something and save it to the array, when I write it to the textfile, the textfile just shows this:

```
System.String[,]
System.String[,]
System.String[,]
```

shows that 20 times (which is my upper limit of the array indices)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 int[,] BookList_Array = new BookList_Array[2,2];
for (int x = 0; x < BookList_Array.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < BookList_Array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                  writer.WriteLine(BookList_Array[x,j].ToString());
            }

    }
```

Comment: That only writes the first element. AA nested loop will be needed eventually.

Comment: @kostas this is throwing up an exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the writer.WriteLine line.

Comment: In the above example BookList_Array must be initialized. Look  the code again.